# Reading data from radio button Group asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, radio-group

I'm trying to make a quiz with multiple choice answers
I made this Quiz View model so the instructor can make a quiz for a course and choose the correct answers

```html
 public class QuizMV
    {
        public int CourseIDD { get; set; }
        public int InstructorID { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }

        public int QuizMark { get; set; }
        public  IList<Question> questions { get; set; }
    }
    
      public partial class Question
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        //public Question()
        //{
        //    this.Answers = new HashSet<Answer>();
        //}
    
        public int QuizID { get; set; }
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public int QuestionMark { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual IList<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
        public virtual Quiz Quiz { get; set; }
    }
    
    public partial class Answer
    {
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }
        public int AnswerID { get; set; }
        public string AnswerText { get; set; }
        public bool CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
        public int QuizID { get; set; }
    
        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I'm trying to make the student make this quiz and choose his own answers, but the answers are not showing in the model sent to the controller

```html
for (var i = 0; i< Model.questions.Count(); i++) { 
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label" for="name" style="font-weight: bolder;font-size: x-large;color: #a757e8;">Question #@(i + 1):</label>
      <label style="color: #a757e8;font-size: larger;">(Mark: @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.questions[i].QuestionMark))</label>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;">
          @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.questions[i].QuestionID) @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.questions[i].QuestionText)
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  @for (var j = 0; j< Model.questions[i].Answers.Count(); j++) { <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">

      <div style="display:inline-block">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.questions[i].Answers[i].CorrectAnswer,"true") @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.questions[i].Answers[j].AnswerText) @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.questions[i].Answers[j].AnswerText)


      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    }
    </div>
    }
```

Can anyone help me to Access the answers in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass selected AnswerText to controller,you can do like this:

Model(add `SelectedAnswerText` ):

```
public partial class Question
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        //public Question()
        //{
        //    this.Answers = new HashSet<Answer>();
        //}
    
        public int QuizID { get; set; }
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public int QuestionMark { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual IList<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
        public virtual Quiz Quiz { get; set; }

       public string SelectedAnswerText { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult TestQuizMV() {
            QuizMV q = new QuizMV { questions = new List<Question> { new Question { QuestionID=1, QuestionMark=3, QuestionText="q1",Answers=new List<Answer> { new Answer {  AnswerID=1, AnswerText="A",CorrectAnswer=true}, new Answer { AnswerID = 2, AnswerText = "B", CorrectAnswer = false }, new Answer { AnswerID = 3, AnswerText = "C", CorrectAnswer = false } } },
            new Question { QuestionID=2, QuestionMark=2, QuestionText="q2",Answers=new List<Answer> { new Answer {  AnswerID=1, AnswerText="A",CorrectAnswer=false}, new Answer { AnswerID = 2, AnswerText = "B", CorrectAnswer = true }, new Answer { AnswerID = 3, AnswerText = "C", CorrectAnswer = false } } },
            new Question { QuestionID=3, QuestionMark=3, QuestionText="q3",Answers=new List<Answer> { new Answer {  AnswerID=1, AnswerText="A",CorrectAnswer=false}, new Answer { AnswerID = 2, AnswerText = "B", CorrectAnswer = false }, new Answer { AnswerID = 3, AnswerText = "C", CorrectAnswer = true } } }} };
            return View(q);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult TestQuizMV(QuizMV quizMV) {
            return Ok();
        }
```

View:

```
<form method="post" id="myform">
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.questions.Count(); i++)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="label" for="name" style="font-weight: bolder;font-size: x-large;color: #a757e8;">Question #@(i + 1):</label>
                    <label style="color: #a757e8;font-size: larger;">(Mark: @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.questions[i].QuestionMark))</label>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12" style="font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.questions[i].QuestionID) @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.questions[i].QuestionText)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @for (var j = 0; j < Model.questions[i].Answers.Count(); j++)
            {<div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <div style="display:inline-block">
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.questions[i].Answers[j].CorrectAnswer,true, new {@class="CorrectAnswer"}) @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.questions[i].Answers[j].AnswerText)
                            <input class="hiddenSelectedAnswerText" hidden asp-for=@Model.questions[i].Answers[j].AnswerText name="questions[@i].SelectedAnswerText" />

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            }
        </div>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

js:

```
<script>
    $("#myform").submit(function () {
        $("div[style='display:inline-block']").each(function () {
            if ($(this).find(".CorrectAnswer").attr("checked") != "checked") {
                var id = $(this).find(".CorrectAnswer").attr("id").replace("CorrectAnswer", "AnswerText");
                $("#" + id).remove();
            }
        })
    })
    </script>
```

result:
[image]